# How to replace a character in a string multiple times?

Tags: string, replace, tuples

Let's say I'm given a `string: a = "Plop"`

Conventionally, replacing a character in a would be `a.replace(character, replacement character)`.
How would I code this to create a `tuple` with different replacements.

For example, I want to change the `"l"` in `"Plop" to either "r" or "i"`, where the outcome would be `("Prop", "Piop")`, rather than just changing a single time `("Prop")`.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you're using Python. You can do that with list comprehension, like so:

```
replacements = ['r', 'i']
replace_character = 'l'
a = "Plot"

tuple([a.replace(replace_character, replacement) for replacement in replacements])
# ('Prot', 'Piot')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You are correct, it is python. Thank you so much! Very concise and easy to follow